# "Unable to initialize module" fileinfo php-pecl-Fileinfo.x86_64

Tags: php5, php

I have a brand new server server that I am trying to get setup up. This is a 64 bit machine that I can not install "fileinfo" or  "memcache". I have uninstalled these and reinstalled them using yum and pecl with no luck. Yum install fine "no error" but then get error when running php. pecl from what I can tell is only installing 32bit. Does not put anything in the lib64 directory. Here is my output from **php -v**:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.2.14 (cli) (built: Aug 12 2010 16:03:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Here is some other system info incase you need it

**uname:**

```
Linux server.actham.us 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Nov 9 12:54:20 EST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**php -m:**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
ctype
curl
date
dbase
dom
exif
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks....

Comment: You are probably doing somtheing like this: http://www.kelvinwong.ca/2010/04/11/installing-fileinfo-on-centos-with-php-5-2-13/

Comment: Did you compile PHP? If not, which repo? Do you need to use PHP 5.2 or can you use PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there's no feedback I'll post a way that I use. If you're on a Red Hat/CentOS then I've had good experience using the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and [IUS Community Project](http://iuscommunity.org/) packages.

```
#EPEL
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/epel-release-1-1.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
#IUS Community Project
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-6.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
#Install repos
rpm -Uvh epel-release-1-1.ius.el5.noarch.rpm ius-release-1.0-6.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
```

The PHP packages are prefixed with php52 or php53 if you want either of them. There's also APC and Fileinfo packages. You should use PHP 5.3 if you can and Fileinfo is bundled into it. Installing a base PHP with APC is simple:

```
yum install php53-pecl-apc
```

View the other modules if you need to install others like PDO, suhosin, soap, etc.:

```
yum list php53*
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, been wrapped up with business. Thanks for the reply I will give that a try.

Comment: For EPEL you don't need any packages from IUS, you just `dnf install epel-release`...